# How can I include multiple files my initial page load using Node

Tags: javascript, php, node.js

Coming from PHP, I just do ( I'm doing a port from LAMP to MEAN )

```
<?php inlcude "file.hm">
```

Is there a simple way to do this in Node?

Comment: You could easily do this using modules: https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html

Comment: Looks better than what I've seen on the web.  I've seen multiple post suggesting to use a tempting library like underscore or mustache ... why would anyone do this as it seems more complicated.

Comment: No ... I need to include multiple html files .... not add in JS modules.